# Two way video on android XMPP , SIP, or UPD stream?

Tags: android, video, xmpp, sip

I wanna develop a simple two way video call functionality and integrate it within my app.
I found two solutions:

1. Using Android SIP - i will need to handle sending and receiving streams
2. Using XMPP - Jingle - i will need to implement the whole protocol

Problem is that i am pretty new to SIP and do know really understand what the SIP protocol on android already handles and how much of development will be needed. I know on the other hand that XMPP on android is not easy as well especially when working with video streams.

I would love to have people thoughts on which solution would be the best to implement knowing that i want:
1.  a simple working 2way video chat at first
2. extend the functionality to a system of users (i was thining that using XMPP with openfire will cover this easily but im kind of scared regarding the ammount of work to integrate jingle)

If you have any easier solution to integrate audio/video functionality on android i would be glad to hear from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions are the same in a lot of ways.
SIP and XMPP both take care only of the signaling. The media part (video streams, UDP, etc) are done "elsewhere" and with the same set of protocols: RTP and RTCP for transport and control. H.264/VP8 for the video codec, some other codec for voice.

I'd look into WebRTC to see if it has any available code on Android - that would take care of the media parts nicely.